# Template metaprogramming and floating point constant coefficients

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I want to know if there is way/technique in the world of C++ template metaprogramming where I can substitue hard coded floating point coeffients. To make it clearer, I will try to give an example:

Consider that I want to make a method that solves linear equations:

```
y = a * x + b
```

One way is to supply `a`, `x`, `b` as arguments at runtime. This I want to avoid. Consider though that I know `a` and `b` then I could write something like:

```
double linear(double x) {
    return 2.0 * x + 3.0;
}
```

So I know that `a = 2.0`, `b= 3.0`. What I want to do is to extract `a` and `b` from templates, so they are there at compile time, just as being hardcoded. An example method can look like (this is what I would like to write in my code):

```
template <class coefs>
double linear(double x) {
    return coefs::a * x  +  coefs::b;
}
```

Is this possible somehow? Not sure either if my question is clear enough so let me know if I need to rephrase.

Comment: It's certainly [possible](http://ideone.com/7jZVn). Is there anything in particular that's not working for you?

Comment: i guess OP is confused since when you make a template you cant have template pram that is a float.  In a sense you can have <typename T, typename U, int n> but you cant have <typename T, typename U, float x>. Ofc you can instantiate the T to be float, U to be double...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `float` and `double` types can't be template parameters, you'll can't set your coefficients via template parameters, but you can simply hard-code the values.

For instance, this won't work:

```
template<float a_in, float b_in>
struct coeff
{
    static const float a = a_in;
    static const float b = b_in;
};

linear<coeff<2.0, 3.0>>(4.0);
```

But this will:

```
struct coeff
{
    static const float a = 2.0;
    static const float b = 3.0;
};

linear<coeff>(4.0);
```

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, once you have defined coeff, you can then use it as your template parameter to the linear template function.

Comment: @Jason You can't initialize `static const float` members like that in `C++03` and for `C++11` it is a good idea to use `constexpr`.